# Object error with trying to return documents (Umbraco Document API)

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco, content-management

I'm working on a recursive method that displays all documents I have permissions to see.  The first pass works great, but when it calls itself recursively passing a document array of the current document's children it throws an error:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Here's the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTest.Text = "Data<br /><br />";
    Document[] releaseDocs = Document.GetRootDocuments();
    displayDocs(releaseDocs);
}
public void displayDocs(Document[] releaseDocs)
{
    string docPermissions = null;
    User currentUser = User.GetCurrent();
    foreach (var doc in releaseDocs)
    {
        docPermissions = currentUser.GetPermissions(doc.Path);
        if ((docPermissions.Contains("F")) && (docPermissions.Contains("U")))
        {
            lblTest.Text += "D/T: " + doc.CreateDateTime + "<br />\r\n";
            lblTest.Text += "Level: " + doc.Level + "<br />\r\n";
            lblTest.Text += "Text: " + doc.Text + "<br />\r\n";
            lblTest.Text += "<hr />\r\n";
            if (doc.HasChildren)
            {
                 Document[] childDocs = Document.GetChildrenForTree(doc.Id);
                 displayDocs(childDocs); //error occurs here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the Document.GetChildrenForTree(doc.Id) method returns a null?

Comment: I thought of that and dropped a try/catch around it.  It's still failing on me though.  I also verified HasChildren was set to true before I call it.  Not that you can rely on that, but theoretically if it "has" children, then it shouldn't be null.

Comment: This may be one to ask on our.umbraco.org